# How to subtract one mesh from another but leaving holes without adding any new faces

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, faces

I have a cylinder and I subtract a cube from it. The result looks as follows

[image]

However, it adds this extra face in the center. I want to get rid of that face and have a hollow object instead. I am using Mesh Boolean in geometry nodes.

Comment: that's how booleans work. If you want to delete that face, you have to "delete" in manually with "delete geometry" (type: face)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Chris has already pointed out, you would have to remove the added face afterwards.

You can do this by marking the faces of the cube with `Capture Attribute` before. This marking remains after `Mesh Boolean` on the resulting mesh, so you can remove this face directly with `Delete Geometry`.

[image]